# ProgressBar with script onPageStarted and onPageFinished

Tags: android, webview, android-progressbar

How to use onPageStarted and onPageFinished to display the  **progress bar**  in WebView, based on  my **MainActivity** ? I currently use Android Studio 2.3.3

**MainActivity**

```js
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
        wv.loadUrl("https://www.google.com);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ws.setSupportZoom(false);

               }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ProgressBar progressBar;
```

...

```
progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
progressBar.setMax(100);
progressBar.setProgress(1);

webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            progressBar.setProgress(progress);
        }
    });
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }



        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I added onPageStarted and onPageFinished. It does not show any errors in the log, but in the app (Smartphone) it does not display the progress bar before opening the URL in WebView. Follow the Code

Comment: in your layout, in the progressbar add: android:visibility="visible" />

Answer (score 0):

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView wv;
ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    if (wv.canGoBack()) {
        wv.goBack();
    } else {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle("Sair")
                .setMessage("Você deseja sair do aplicativo?")
                .setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }

                })
                .setNegativeButton("Não", null)
                .show();
    }
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);

    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebClient());
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    wv.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
}


public class WebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


}
```

}